# underscore _.object but with duplicate handler function, possible?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I don't want to remove the duplicates, I want to be able to handle the duplicate with a function.

Any ideas on how to nicely do it in a `_.chain`?

```
_.chain(users)
    .map(function(user)
    {
        return [user.username, user]
    })
    .object() //but handle the duplicate collisions instead of losing them
    .value();
```

Specifically, I want to change the username when I get a username collision, ideally with something like:

```
 .object(values, function duplicateHandler(value)
{
     value.username = value.username + '_' + 1;
});
```

If it also could reapply itself to re-check for uniqueness, that would be awesome.

Comment: You probably just want to use `_.groupBy(user, "username")`?

Comment: well yes, the long way would be to group by username, rename and retry again until there are no more collisions, i just thought it was a common case that could be solved nicely.

Comment: I wonder what you're trying to do. Append `_1` to all property names? Probably it would be much more easy to just write the code without underscore.

Comment: I did do it eventually with groupBy and it worked nicely, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to group all the records with the same user name together in an array:

```
_.chain(users)
    .groupBy('username')
    .value();
```

Or this to handle them some other way you like

```
_.chain(users)
    .groupBy('username')
    .map(function(userArray, username) { ... })
    .object()
    .value();
```

For example:

```
var users = [ 
    { username: 'one' }, 
    { username: 'two' }, 
    { username: 'two' } 
];

var obj = 
    _.chain(users)
        .groupBy('username')
        .map(function(userArray, username) { 
            return (userArray.length === 1)
                ? [[username, userArray[0]]]
                : _.map(userArray, function(v, i) {
                    return [username + '_' + (i+1), v]
                });
        })
        .flatten(true)
        .object()
        .value();

console.log(obj);
```

Will produce:

```
{one: Object, two_1: Object, two_2: Object}
```

Where *`Object`* represents a reference the original object declared in `users`.

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/4CpD8/1/)